# Logging device id in database from data collection app

Tags: web

App A is communicating to database X through web service Y. Service Y enables insert, update and delete operations to data in database X. Many authorized people can use app A and connect to database X through service Y.
Developer Q wants to create a database trigger to log some  information about the entries and updates on a table in database X including device id or IP. Can developer Q access some device identity through the established connection to database X through service Y?
If he/she can't, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer yes. The how is a bit more involved. You did not include what language the web service is written in so keeping it high level and focusing on the implementation agnostic way first.

Most languages used to code web services capture request information - device info, web client info, ip address (not reliable though), authentication identification (if not anonymous access), etc. So one typical way to track this data is create a session table in the database that you write all the pertinent request data to for web service session. Then derive a key for each session. Finally add a column for the session key to each table you execute DML on. Alternate approach is to have an operational table (what you already have) and a matching log table. the operational table doesn't have a session  key column, but the logging table does. There are other ways to log activity, these are just some to demonstrate the point.

Another way, OO example, is to create a derived connection class that you add in web service session info to. This can then be accessed at the database command execution, usually done via a command object, and instead of writing triggers you programmatically do the logging.

In your particular case, the latter approach seems more appropriate than triggers since triggers could fire when someone does DML on the database directly, or another interface instead of the web service. In which case there would be no request info to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for your input Hubson, I think now I have a clear picture of what I need to do.